# Как можно мониторить интернет соединение?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Выполняю post запрос в другом потоке с помощью AsyncTask, пока он выполняется, прогрессбар крутиться, сворачиваю приложение, выключаю вайфай, приложение падает! Интересует 2 вопроса, можно ли в режиме реального времени следить за наличием соединения и как прервать запрос?

```
protected Void doInBackground (String... params) 
    {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
         HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(УРЛ);

            try {

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("login", "майлогин"));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", "майпасс"));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                // Execute HTTP Post Request
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
                String str = new String();
                str = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());     
                publishProgress(str);

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(SigiActivity.this, "Ошибка : " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            }

        return null;    
    }
```

Comment: В смысле? cURL`om что ли?

Comment: Не понял вопроса

Comment: А я ваш. Как можно отправить запрос и он вдруг обрывается?

Comment: ты про программу в общем? или сам пишешь? в дебагере можно

Answer (score 5, accepted):

За наличием подключения к Wi-Fi или сети оператор (подключение к сети не означает доступность интернета!) следить можно. Но в вашем случае не вижу в этом необходимости. Если инет пропал во время выполнения запроса, будет выкинуто исключение IOException - нужно только перехватить его и правильно обработать.

В вашем коде вижу блок

```
} catch (IOException e) {
    Toast.makeText(SigiActivity.this, "Ошибка : " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
}
```

Toast относится к UI, а из метода doInBackground не должен вызываться никакой код, работающий с UI. Скорее всего из-за этого и падает приложение.

Правильным будет в методе doInBackground возвращать результат, содержащий признак успешности запроса и/или другие нужные данные, а в метод onPostExecution вынести код, выдающий что-то на экран в зависимости от результата запроса.

Comment: Заработало! Благодарен!

Answer (score 1):

Вы в отладчик заглядывали? Скорее всего у вас нету обработки ошибок работы с HTTP. Покажите хотябы код, чтобы можно было давать вам более развернутые советы. Или сами оберните функцию передачи `POST` в `try-catch`.

Comment: не могу воспроизвести ошибку на эмуляторе, она происходит на физическом устройстве!

Comment: Поставьте из маркета aLogCat или подключите девайс компьютеру через usb и смотрите logcat прям в эклипсе.