# Проверка на соединение интернет

Tags: android

В AsynsTask посылаю get запрос

```
try {

                URL url = new URL(params[0]);
                urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();
                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line);
                }
                resultJson = buffer.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                httpClient.onError(e.getMessage());
                return null;
            }
```

Когда есть соединение с интернетом все нормально, но когда нет приложение завершает работу ошибкой. Вопрос. Как правильно решить эту проблему?

Comment: посмотри вот это: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7994544/async-task-network-error

Comment: Покажите код в методе ```onPostExecute```. Полагаю что вы пытаетесь обратиться к ```null```

Comment: Посмотрите здесь: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/89308/

Answer (score 2):

Можно перед отправкой запроса проверять наличие соединения, и если оно есть, то запрос посылать, в противном случае выдавать сообщение об отсутствии соединения. выглядит примерно так:

```
    if (!isOnline()) {
                connectDialog();
            }else{
// do need work}
```

проверка соединения:

```
  protected boolean isOnline() {
        String cs = Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE;
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)
                getSystemService(cs);
        return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null;
    }
```

сообщение об отсутствии соединения:

```
 public void connectDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Нет доступа к интернету");
        builder.setMessage("Для работы с приложением требуется соединение с интернетом.\n" +
                "Включите доступ к интернету!");
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setPositiveButton("Ок", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
              }
        });
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
    }
```

Comment: Это как вариант, но, насколько я знаю, предложенный код проверяет лишь наличие соединения с к-л сетью, но не наличие в ней интернета. К тому же, интернет может пропасть и после начала запроса.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб да вы правы,  можно узнать ваш вариант?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб что по вашему лучше отловить ошибку об отсутствии интернета и обработать ее или постоянно проверять его наличие? хочется узнать ваше экспертное мнение

Comment: ИМХО, лучше отлавливать ошибку соединения, чем проверять наличие интернета, т.к. он в любой момент может появиться/исчезнуть и любая инфа о его наличии будет актуальна только в момент проверки)